# Migrate .NET Framework 4.x projects to .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a project in .net framework, now I want to convert it to .netcore. what will be steps for doing this migration

Comment: Reading the docs?

Answer (score 2):

From MS Documentation

> 1. Retarget all projects you wish to port to target .NET Framework 4.7.2 or higher.
> 2. Use the .NET Portability Analyzer to analyze your assemblies and see if they're portable to .NET Core.
> 3. Install the .NET API analyzer into your projects to identify APIs that throw PlatformNotSupportedException on some platforms and some other potential compatibility issues.
> 4. Convert all of your packages.config dependencies to the PackageReference format with the conversion tool in Visual Studio.
> 5. Create new projects for .NET Core and copy over source files, or attempt to convert your existing project file with a tool.
> 6. Port your test code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/

Enjoy reading... ;-)